# Creating Django Cache table using South?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-south

We use South for our schemamigrations and datamigrations. Now I need to enable the cache in Django which is quite simple to do. That forced me to use `manage.py createcachetable cache_table` in my terminal. Though I would like to automate this process with South. Is there a way I can create a cache table using South ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new South datamigration (just a blank migration):
`python manage.py datamigration <app> create_cache_table`

Edit the generated migration. I called my cache table simply `cache`.

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models
from django.core.management import call_command # Add this import

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        call_command('createcachetable', 'cache')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.delete_table('cache')

    ...
```

If you are using multiple databases and need to define which to use. Note the second import statement for `dbs` instead of `db`. You also will need to set up routing instructions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#multiple-databases.

```
import datetime
from south.db import dbs # Import dbs instead of db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models
from django.core.management import call_command # Add this import

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        call_command('createcachetable', 'cache', database='other_database')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        dbs['other_database'].delete_table('cache')

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks looks like exactly what I wanted :)